# Use Hadoop as MySQL storage engine?

Tags: mysql, database, hadoop, hdfs

besides using Hive, is it a good idea in order to execute ad hoc query on large scale log data on HDFS for SQL programmers?

Is there any similar open-source implementation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically it should not be that complicated to implement. Some conceptual problem I see with it that performance-wise behavior of the NoSQL engines is fundamentally different from what MySQL engine expect from storage engines. Specifically - they have good random access and not that efficient in the full or range scans. The question is it will be possible to translate all these costs to the optimizer. It is something applicable to any RDBMS engine. Actually many of them has a concept of pluggable storage engines and have different level of flexibility / documentation. 
 
I think, to have such integration efficient we need to be able to push down predicates to the NoSQL engines for the full / range scans. I am not 100% sure that MySQL supports it on the level of storage engine interface. 
Another serious problem I see with this approach - the fact that MySQL does not have parallel query, and thereof can not be too good for processing big data.

Answer (score 1):

I search the question in 2014 and I found [Infinidb](http://www.infinidb.co/products) and [a blog](http://www.percona.com/blog/2014/06/02/using-infinidb-engine-mysql-hadoop-cluster-data-analytics/) about it. It integrate hadoop and mysql. It provide a native mysql protocol access to data stored hadoop.

I've not reading much about it, while it is questionable to me in compatibility(with existing app for mysql) and performance(compare to well tuned index and data partitioning).

But it might be the easiest solution for high-availability with really large dataset which cannot fit into few disks. (using HDFS build-in replication, no SAN or RAID will be needed)

BTW, the Infinidb website is currently affected by the Heartbleed bug. I wonder if their product secure as the yet patch the heardbleed for more then 5 months.

Comment: InfiniDB (aka Calpont) went out of business on the date of your post. Support (and theoretical future development) is now being offered by MariaDB (the company, previously SkySQL).